# Completing multiple insurance quotation forms - Selenium? Python? Other?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm trying to complete a number of webpage insurance quotation forms, both stand alone and through aggregators.

I'm currently using Selenium through Firefox, which is broadly ok and works, but means I can only run one script at a time (need to run over a dozen).

Is there a better way of doing this?  Even just a way of playing multiple selenium scripts simultaneously would do the job.

In an ideal world, each script would run simultaneously, return the reference at the end of the quotation page and put each reference into a specific field in a separate form.

Many thanks in advance,

Rupe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery) that is used to run periodic tasks or run tasks in specific times. The following example demonstrates a function that will run every 10seconds so every 10seconds one form will be completed.

```
from datetime import timedelta
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), max_retries=0)
def fill_forms():
    # your operations...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since running multiple scripts in multiple terminal windows doesn't work, try running different scripts on different browsers. Probably not the best answer, but it should be a doable and simple approach.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp